# Chaining action modes

Tags: android

In my activity, I have an action mode defined as follows.

```
@Override
public void onShowPlace(final String placeId, final String placeName) {
    Log.i("PLACE", placeId);

    actionModeFeedByLocation = startSupportActionMode(new ActionMode.Callback(){
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle(placeName);
            om.slideHorizontal(R.id.overlay_nf_bylocation_fragment_container,
                    NewsfeedFragment.newInstance(om), TAG_NFBYLOCATION_FRAGMENT);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            Log.i("DESTROY_ACTIONMODE", "TEST");
            om.back();
        }
    });
}
```

This renders a newsfeed for a single place in an overlay fragment.
From this feed, I want to show the detail in yet a second overlay by creating another action mode:

```
@Override
public void onShowUser(final User user) {
    actionModeUserProfile = startSupportActionMode(new ActionMode.Callback(){
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle(user.getFbName());
            om.slideHorizontal(R.id.overlay_nf_userprofile_fragment_container,
                    UserProfileFragment.newInstance(user.getFbId(), user.getFbName(), user.getGender()), TAG_USERPROFILE_FRAGMENT);
            Log.i("ACTION_MODE", String.valueOf(actionModeFeedByLocation == actionModeUserProfile));

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            om.back();
        }
    });

}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work; the call to the detail of the user destroys the first action mode.

I use action mode to maintain consistent "back" behaviour.
As illustration, this is what I need to achieve visually:

[image]

It is important to note that:

- These fragment appear as overlays on top of each other (should not be destroyed unless "back" is called on them, so I created containers for each in the activity xml)
- The "home" (first) screen has set a toolbar to the SupportActionBar

What I need is the back button (in the header + device button) to behave consistently on each overlay, and remove each later correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by overriding `onBackPressed`and `onOptionsItemSelected`, and manually syncing the toolbars title / managing the fragment backstack through custom code in the aforementioned callbacks.